# How to remove a specific pattern in a string in R?

Tags: r, string

I have this string:

```
str <- c("the author (p. j. Wittgenstein)", "n = 10", "arjen lubach")
```

I want to remove every single letter that is followed by a point.
However, I can't figure out how to combine both aspects in a command. The output should look like this:

```
"the author ( Wittgenstein)" "n = 10" "arjen lubach")
```

I am currently trying

```
gsub(" ?\\<[[:alpha:](?=\\.)]\\> ?", "", str)
```

But that does not do the job :-(

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a look-ahead or look-behind expression for this:

```
gsub("[A-Za-z]\\.", "", str)
```

Add `\\s` if you want to remove the space as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was a well-working and simple answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(str, "[[:alpha:]]\\.")
```